How to solve the problem "No resource found that matches the given name" in arrays.xml?
Error
code


<string-array name="com.google.firebase.crashlytics.build_ids_arch">

<item>aarch64</item><item>aarch64</item><item>arm</item><item>arm</item></string-array>

<string-array name="com.google.firebase.crashlytics.build_ids_build_id"><item>1dc5e1549c21c8427b793e2719047376293f9cdf</item><item>22877777dbfadf9ae60a3dcd10bb9ae6d42bf1a6</item><item>612931405d4dac951d04761b8b50886d78135138</item><item>29e677390c24224f2f0d19c19871dc2772b3b7e1</item></string-array>

<string-array name="com.google.firebase.crashlytics.build_ids_lib"><item>libanzu.so</item><item>libgrowtopia.so</item><item>libanzu.so</item><item>libgrowtopia.so</item></string-array>

I don't know what to do anymore, is there anyone who can solve my problem?

Welcome to StackOverflow, please don't post images of code or error messages. Instead copy and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly.
